# count ones in range

Tags: code-golf, math, number, binary

## Challenge :

Count the number of ones `1` in the binary representation of all number between a range.

---

## Input :

Two non-decimal positive integers

---

## Output :

The sum of all the `1`s in the range between the two numbers.

---

## Example :

```
4 , 7        ---> 8
4  = 100 (adds one)   = 1
5  = 101 (adds two)   = 3
6  = 110 (adds two)   = 5
7  = 111 (adds three) = 8

10 , 20     ---> 27
100 , 200   ---> 419
1 , 3       ---> 4
1 , 2       ---> 2
1000, 2000  ---> 5938
```

I have only explained the first example otherwise it would have taken up a huge amount of space if I tried to explain for all of them.

---

## Note :

- Numbers can be apart by over a 1000
- All input will be valid.
- The minimum output will be one.
- You can accept number as an array of two elements.
- You can choose how the numbers are ordered.

---

## Winning criteria :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

Comment: [OEIS A000788](http://oeis.org/A000788)

Comment: May we take the input as some kind of range type (`IntRange` in Kotlin, `Range` in Ruby)?

Comment: Fun fact: case `1000 - 2000` yields 5938, but lower the case by 1000, the result also drops by 1000: `0-1000 = 4938`. [Proof](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/IyS34////Bpz/DQ0MDAA)

Comment: @steenbergh Consider 0-2000 + 1000. For 0<=i<1000, pair i with (2i,2i+1), then <0-2000,1000> is 2 times <0-1000> plus 1000 extra 1's. Removing a 0-1000 is, 1000-2000 is <0-1000> + 1000

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>(g=c=>a>b?0:1+g(c^c&-c||++a))(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsIwEIXhvaeYlWQItUksVAuJNxGmYxuU0kgrrnr3GDGr4OZtPt7/oDetvNyfr2oOtyGONpJ1vXXCW7aOXH9RnZZe8JX3FW@blIQoCCOHeQ3TcJiCF6MAaDBNiwh1DaddoVolNeqnpi1Yq8RGZW70ubyD/saP2f@ryfH4AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => b => (         // given the input values a and b
  g = c =>          // g = recursive function taking c = current value
    a > b ?         // if a is greater than b:
      0             //   stop recursion and return 0
    :               // else:
      1 +           //   add 1 to the final result
      g(            //   and do a recursive call to g() with:
        c ^ c & -c  //     the current value with the least significant bit thrown away
        || ++a      //     or the next value in the range if the above result is 0
      )             //   end of recursive call
)(a)                // initial call to g() with c = a
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y:y/x and bin(x).count('1')+f(x+1,y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzNCsIwEAbP@hTfpSRLV21aQSjou6SWYEA3paSQPH38iZeZOc2S4yNIX4q7Pu1rmi0S5zGfEqzMmLzoRMd72CRqZRS1TqfWcKbiwgqdGJngBfrMuBBDm47Rd7V@WZsx/N3TuN8tq5cI1Qwb4wMcbl8pNHXJcHVN5Q0)

Comment: Clever trick to avoid `>=`...

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
rBFS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/IyS34////Jv/NAQ)

#### Explanation

```
rBFS – Full program. Takes the two inputs from the commands line arguments.
r    – Range.
 B   – For each, convert to binary.
  FS – Flatten and sum.
```

Comment: O_o , that was fast ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Well, the challenge is also kind of trivial IMO.

Comment: It may be, but an answer a minute after posting.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Yes, that's not really that fast for trivial challenges like this one; knowledge of Jelly also ensues. The real effort goes in e.g. the language of this month, QBasic. ;-)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer : Can you answer this in QBasic / BrainF**k ?

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ŸbSO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6I6kYP///024zAE)

Comment: Exactly the solution I got :). +1.

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 55 bytes

```java
a->b->{int c=0;for(;a<=b;)c+=a.bitCount(b--);return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BS8QwEIXv/RVzTNQED4KHbAsiCB7Ew@JJPEyyaUlNk5BMFsrS317j6umbx5uZ92Y8o5hP37tbUswEc9OykvNyrMGQi0HeqM54LAXe0AW4dACpau8MFEJqOEd3gqV57EjZhenzCzBPhV9XAV7@/xxeA9nJ5rvGj4B5fU82I8U8wNjvKAYthosLBKa/V2PMTOGh14qb2x6ldvQcayCmheAqW6o5gFHbrq4Zx7WQXWSsJFOrQD6wUWJKfmUP/G94Ki2XPXL@e7F12/4D)

Comment: `IntStream.range(a,b+1).map(Integer::bitCount).sum()`

Comment: @saka1029 The imports are mandatory. So it's actually `a->b->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(a,b+1).map(Integer::bitCount).sum()`, for a whole 74 bytes. Even if the the import wasn't mandatory, the parameters are, so we'd have to write `a->b->IntStream.range(a,b+1).map(Integer::bitCount).sum()`, which counts as 57 bytes

Comment: You could also have `a->b->IntStream.range(a,b+1).map(Long::bitCount).sum()` for a 1 byte improvement. Marginal, but still one.

Comment: @NotBaal As mentioned by Olivier in the comment above, imports are mandatory, so it should be `a->b->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(a,b+1).map(Long::bitCount).sum()` (71 bytes).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:`map(bin,range(x,y+1))`.count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwFETXeorZlOTjV5pUEAp6EhdN1WihTUJJwZw@VuNm3mMGJqT48k5nizOueTRTfzd4c2q7yQTZD45n454PuVY7RdQdbn5xUQolKFs/Yx2QCIODPDJOxJCqZui62E@LM5o/NbXbTZgHFyGqZmGsgf3lC4GqXDJsuab8AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder.

```
ssjR2}F
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ssjR2%7DF&input=4%2C7&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
&:Bz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X83Kqer/fxMucwA)

*Thanks to Luis Mendo for saving a byte!*

```
(implicit input a and b, a<b)
&:                              % two-element input range, construct [a..b]
  B                             % convert to Binary as a logical vector (matrix)
   z                            % number of nonzero entries
(implicit output of the result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>41</s> 34 bytes

```r
function(a,b)sum(intToBits(a:b)>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJs7g0VyMzryQk3ymzpFgj0SpJ085A83@ahomOuSZXmoahgY6RAYQBYkGYOsYQykjzPwA)

Heavily inspired by [the other R solution by ngm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166216/80010). This uses a different approach after the conversion to bits. Huge thanks to Giuseppe for hinting at a possible 34 bytes solution.

Comment: 34 bytes is possible! I forget where I saw the trick (I know I didn't come up with it) but there's a trickier conversion to a `sum`mable vector -- I'll post if you/ngm can't find it.

Comment: @Giuseppe Indeed!

Comment: I got it down to [37 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166216/79980) using a technique that might otherwise be useful. Also discovered that `sd` and `var` coerce anything they can to double.

Comment: You can use `pryr::f` to save 4 bytes: https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTaO4NFcjM68kJN8ps6RYI9EqSdPOQFPzf5qGiY65JleahqGBjpEBhAFiQZg6xhDKSPM/AA

Comment: @pajonk good point! But I'm trying to stick to the base R packages rather than R+pryr. I'm going to search on meta what can be considered "pure R".

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>56</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

<s>This can be golfed more imo.</s> 
-2 Bytes thanks to Mr.Xcoder
-2 More bytes thanks to M. I. Wright

```python
lambda a,b:''.join(map(bin,range(a,b+1))).count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fbhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8lKXV0vKz8zTyM3sUAjKTNPpygxLz1VAyijbaipqamXnF@aV6Khbqiu@b@gKBPITNcw0THX1ORC8Cw0Nf8DAA)

Comment: You can in fact use `str()` instead of `''.join()`, because all the extra characters don't change the `.count('1')`

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{("%b"*(b-a+1)%[*a..b]).count ?1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6laQ0k1SUlLI0k3UdtQUzVaK1FPLylWUy85vzSvRMHesPZ/QWlJsUJatImOeex/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{≢⍸(⍵⍴2)⊤⍺↓0,⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR56JHvTs0HvVufdS7xUjzUdeSR727HrVNNtB51LsZKFr7//@j3rkK4Zk5OQq5idmpCpklCkmpJSWpRQo5iUBSj4vL0MBAoVr7Uc9@HTzGKBgZGAAA)

-1 thanks to [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz).

Left argument = min
Right argument = max

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with Communication toolbox, 21 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b)nnz(de2bi(a:b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSTMvr0ojJdUoKVMj0SpJU/N/moaJjrkmV5qGoYGOkQGEAWJBmDrGEMpI8z8A)

The code should be fairly obvious. Number of nonzero elements in the binary representation of each of the numbers in the range.

This would be `@(a,b)nnz(dec2bin(a:b)-48)` without the communication toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 2 bytes

```
ṡb
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwi4bmhYiIsIiIsIjRcbjciXQ==) or see a [four byte flagless version](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuaFiZuKIkSIsIiIsIjRcbjciXQ==).

Gets the range between the two inputs, converts each to a list of 1s and 0s, then deep flattens and sums with the `d` flag.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>44 40</s> 37 bytes

```r
function(a,b)sum(c(0,intToBits(a:b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJs7g0VyNZw0AnM68kJN8ps6RYI9EqSVNT83@ahomOueZ/AA)

Previously:

```r
function(a,b)sum(strtoi(intToBits(a:b)))
function(a,b)sum(as.integer(intToBits(a:b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
çy╠Æ¼☻
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8779cc92ac02&i=4+7&a=1)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>33</s> 26 bytes

Prompts for vector of integers:

```
+/,((↑v)⍴2)⊤(1↓v)+0,⍳-/v←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5r6@toaDxqm1im@ah3i5Hmo64lGoaP2iaXaWob6Dzq3ayrXwZUC9TzH6j6fxqXuYIJVxqXkYGCoQGYBjFALGMFQxBfwRAA)

Explanation:

```
v←⎕ prompt for input of a vector of two integers max first

(v←1↓v)+0,⍳-/ create a vector of integers from min to max

(↑v)⍴2 set max power of 2 to max 

⊤ convert integers to a matrix of binaries

+/, convert matrix to a vector and sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 72 bytes

```powershell
param($x,$y)$x..$y|%{$o+=([convert]::ToString($_,2)-replace0).length};$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoMwDADQy2TQMi3RT8VTuD@RUSSoUJuSlU3RnT2@l/hH8lkoBNXkxW8G9gIOC7tzcFyPE/jZmWHi@CXJY9O8uM@yxtnAu6htKZSCnwitCxTnvPxbYFWtELVGvAE)

Long because of the conversion to binary `[convert]::ToString($_,2)` and getting rid of the zeros `-replace0`. Otherwise we just take the input numbers, make a range `$x..$y` and for each number in the range convert it to binary, remove the zeros, take the `.length` thereof (i.e., the number of ones remaining), and add it to our `$o`utput.

Comment: try to use `count` instead `length` :)

Comment: @mazzy `count` will always be `1` because we're counting the `length` of a string, not an array.

Comment: string! you are right. thanks. `-replace0` is smart.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + common utilities, 50

```bash
jot -w%o - $@|tr 247356 1132|fold -1|paste -sd+|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Pyu/REG3XDVfQVdBxaGmpEjByMTc2NRMwdDQ2KgmLT8nRUHXsKYgsbgkVUG3OEW7Jin5////hgb/jQwA)

Converting integers to binary strings is always a bit of pain in bash.  The approach here is slightly different - convert the integers to octal, then replace each octal digit with the number of binary 1s it contains.  Then we can just sum all converted digits

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
⟦₂ḃᵐcọht
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9icmFjaHlsb2cy///in6bigoLhuIPhtZBj4buNaHT//1sxMCwyMF3/Wg)

#### Explanation

```
⟦₂         Ascending range between the two elements in the input
  ḃᵐ       Map to base 2
    c      Concatenate
     ọ     Occurrences of each element
      h    Head: take the list [1, <number of occurrences of 1>]
       t   Tail: the number of occurrences of 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 69 bytes

```forth
: f 1+ 0 -rot swap do i begin 2 /mod -rot + swap ?dup 0= until loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NDsIgEITvPsWk14ZK8S9poz6LilSS2t0gjY@PC3iZ@TazmXEU4ktNLltKAxz6FhoqUMTne2NYgsf9OfkFBts32Zq1Nb3alaHPWJfoZ8xEjFFaGCYH5eWALlTpGkCpSyMjx3w/wrjppZVFd6J7nDJrGF08w58KCqcf)

#### Explanation

The basic algorithm is to loop over every number in range, and sum the binary digits (divide by two, add remainder to sum, repeat until number is 0)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
1+                   \ add one to the higher number to make it inclusive
0 -rot swap          \ create a sum value of 0 and put loop parameters in high low order
do                   \ start a loop over the range provided
  i                  \ place the index on the stack
  begin              \ start an indefinite loop
    2 /mod           \ get the quotient and remainder of dividing by 2
    -rot             \ move the quotient to the back
    + swap           \ add the remainder to the sum and move it down the stack
    ?dup             \ duplicate the quotient unless it equals 0
    0=               \ check if it equals 0
  until              \ if it does equal 0, end the inner loop
loop                 \ end the outer loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Σṁḋ…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zihzsbH@7oftSw7P///yb/zQE)

#### Explanation

```
Σṁḋ…
   …     Get the (inclusive) range.
 ṁḋ      Convert each to binary and concatenate.
Σ        Get the sum.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 31 bytes

Saved one byte thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).

```
a->b->sum(i=a,b,sumdigits(i,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9R1y5J1664NFcj0zZRJ0kHyErJTM8sKdbI1DHS1PxfUJSZV6KRpmGiqWEO5AIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-x`, <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
òV ®¤è1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CmMIVD6w4tObzC8P9/EwVzLt0KAA)

Comment: 8 bytes: `òV m¤¬è1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), <s>[40](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/166208/1)</s> 37 bytes

```
x=>y=>str(map(bin,x..y+1)).count("1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@7/C1q7S1q64pEgjN7FAIykzT6dCT69S21BTUy85vzSvREPJUEnzf0FRJpCZpmGiqWGuqfkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-x`, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Takes input as an array of 2 integers.

```
rõ ®¤¬x
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=cvUgrqSseA==&input=WzQsN10KLXg=)

---

### Explanation

```
rõ          :Reduce by inclusive range
   ®        :Map
    ¤       :  Convert to binary string
     ¬      :  Split
      x     :  Reduce by addition
            :Implicitly reduce by addition and output
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 97 Bytes

(sure this can be shortened, but wanted to use the functions)

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReFm0Qa2tiDWUbxtqaW3PZ2wEV2BaXJhWXFMUn55fmlWhk5hbk5KekaiQWFSVWxucmFmikleYll2Tm52molGlWF6WWlBblKaSkJidlgkWsa3WKEvPSUzVgdujALNDU1NQx1LT@/x8A)

**Code**

```
<?=substr_count(implode(array_map(function($v){return decbin($v);},
 range($argv[0],$argv[1]))),1);
```

**Explanation**

```
<?=
 substr_count(   //Implode the array and count every "1"
  implode(
    array_map(function($v){return decbin($v);}, //Transform every decimal to bin
          range($argv[0],$argv[1])   //generate a range between the arguments
     )
),1);   //count "1"'s
```

Comment: it seems you can just do [this](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReFm0Qa2toYGAN5RnG2hqBePZ2QEW2xaVJxSVF8cn5pXklGpm5BTn5KakaiUVFiZXxuYkFGimpyUmZeTpFiXnpqRow03RgBmlqauoYalr//w8A)

Comment: For a second i absolutely forgot that you can set php function's name directly as a parameter :-(

Comment: `$argv[0]` is the program name or "-"; You should work with `$argv[1]` and `$argv[2]`. And you can use `join` instead of `implode`, shortening this to 68 bytes: `<?=substr_count(join(array_map(decbin,range($argv[1],$argv[2]))),1);`

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>19</s> 13 bytes

```
{+//2\x_!1+y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpbX98opiJe0VC7svZ/WrSJtXnsfwA)

`{` `}` is a function with arguments `x` and `y`

`!1+y` is the list 0 1 ... y

`x_` drops the first x elements

`2\` encodes each int as a list of binary digits of the same length (this is specific to ngn/k)

`+/` sum

`+//` sum until convergence; in this case sum of the sum of all binary digit lists

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
import Data.Bits
a%b=sum$popCount<$>[a..b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzymzpJgrUTXJtrg0V6Ugv8A5vzSvxEbFLjpRTy8p9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCioKhgYGqhpGBgZWVZ16JpsJ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
$+JTB:a\,b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRdsrxMkqMUYn6f///4YGBv@NDAwA)

#### Explanation

```
            a and b are command-line args (implicit)
      a\,b  Inclusive range from a to b
   TB:      Convert to binary (: forces TB's precedence down)
  J         Join into a single string of 1's and 0's
$+          Sum (fold on +)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>16, 15</strike> 14 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to FrownyFrog!

```
+/@,@#:@}.i.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9b30HHQdnKoVYvU08n9r8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr6CiUKagjmEaWgAZBsZwDgQHowL5BgjmEb/AQ)

Explanation:

A dyadic verb, the left argument is the lower bound `m` of the range, the right one - the upper `n`.

```
            ,    append                      
             ]   n to the
          i.     list 0..n-1
         }.      drop m elements from the beginning of that list 
      #:@        and convert each element to binary 
    ,@           and flatten the table
 +/@             and find the sum
```

Comment: Can you make it 14?

Comment: @FrownyFrog I'll try later today (apparently it's possible, since you are asking :) )

Comment: @FrownyFrog [15](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D9aW99Bx0HZykFHV08tU@@/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQq2VQloxF1dqcka@grlCmoIJhGlkAGQbGsA4EB6UawziQGVAzP8A) for now, I'm still trying...

Comment: [14](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9b30HHQdnKoVYvU08n9r8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr6CiUKagjmEaWgAZBsZwDgQHowL5BgjmEb/AQ)

Comment: @FrownyFrog Aah, so easy! I was thinking about `}.` but always in a fork and not in a hook. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

*-1 bytes thanks to Brad Gillbert*

```perl6
{[…](@_)>>.base(2).comb.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYKvwvzr6UcOyWA2HeE07O72kxOJUDSNNveT83CS94tLc2v/FiSCFGoYGBjoKRgYGmtZccBGQgOZ/AA)

Explanation:

```perl6
[…](@_)    #Range of parameter 1 to parameter 2
       >>    #Map each number to
                      .sum  #The sum of
                 .comb      #The string of
         .base(2)    #The binary form of the number
```

Comment: You can reduce it by one byte if you use `[...](@_)` instead of `($^a..$^b)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩΣ⭆…·ＮＮ⍘ι²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0VyO4BMhP900s0MjMS84pLc4sSw1KzEtP1fDMKygt8SvNTUot0tDUUUDhAvlOicWpEL0amToKRpogYP3/vwmXxX/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     ＮＮ     Input numbers
   …·       Inclusive range
  ⭆         Map over range and join
        ι   Current value
         ²  Literal 2
       ⍘    Convert to base as string
 Σ          Sum of digits
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, <s>38</s> 32 bytes

```bash
seq -f2o%.fn $*|dc|tr -d 0|wc -c
```

*Thanks to @Cowsquack for golfing off 6 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEE3zShfVS8tT0FFqyYluaakSEE3RcGgpjxZQTf5////hgb/jQwA)

Comment: Nice approach, you can use dc to shave 6 bytes, [`seq -f2o%fp $*|dc|tr -cd 1|wc -c`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEE3zShfNa1AQUWrJiW5pqRIQTc5RcGwpjwZyPj//7@hwX8jAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, <s>95</s> <s>93</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

@DLosc saved me <s>some</s> a lot of bytes!

Saved another byte using [this technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167606/44874)!

```
INPUT a,b
FOR i=a TO b
k=i
FOR j=i TO 0STEP-1
x=k>=2^j
s=s-x
k=k+x*2^j
NEXT j,i
?s
```

Language of the Month FTW!

**Explanation**

```
INPUT a,b           Ask user for lower and upper bound
FOR i=a TO b        Loop through that range
k=i                 we need a copy of i to not break the FOR loop
FOR j=i TO 0STEP-1  We're gonna loop through exponents of 2 from high to low.
                    Setting the first test up for 4 to 2^4 (etc) we know we're overshooting, but that 's OK
x=k>=2^j            Test if the current power of 2 is equal to or smaller than k 
                    (yields 0 for false and -1 for true)
s=s-x               If k is bigger than 2^j, we found a 1, so add 1 to our running total s
                    (or sub -1 from the total s...)
k=k+x*2^j           Lower k by that factor of 2 if the test is true, else by 0
NEXT                Test the next exponent of 2
NEXT                process the next number in range
?s                  print the total
```

Last testcase of 1000 to 2000 actually works, in QBasic 4.5 running on Dosbox:
[image: Hij doet het!]

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
≢⍤⍸⍤⊤…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1Hnoke9Sx717gCRXUseNSz7n/aobcKj3r5HfVM9/R91NR9ab/yobSKQFxzkDCRDPDyD/5sopCmYcxkaACkjAyANYQBZQNoYTBqBRKHCBgA)

`≢` tally

`⍤` of

`⍸` where true

`⍤` in

`⊤` the binary representation of

`…` the range

Comment: … and it looks cute too

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 68 bytes

The [mapping variant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166220/55735) already has been posted (though not yet in it´s mostly golfed version), so here is a looping solution:

```
for($i=$argv[2];$i>=$argv[1];)for($n=$i--;$n;$n>>=1)$s+=$n&1;echo$s;
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c246c535382c7ef118cb522bd43907aed71948a3).

Answer (score 1):

## 6510 machine code, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

sub routine;
takes input from A (lower bound) and X (upper bound) registers;
returns result in A (MSB) and Y (LSB)

**machine code**:

```
85 02 A0 00 84 FC E8 CA
E4 02 30 OD 8A F0 F8 46
90 FB E8 90 F8 E6 FC D0
F4 A5 FC 60
```

**source code:**

```
        STA $02     store lower bound in $02
        LDY #0      init result to 0 (Y = LSB, $FC=MSB)
        STY $FC
        INX         increment upper bound
LOOP1:  DEX         decrement upper bound
        CPX $02     compare to lower bound
        BMI :FINISH if smaller, return
        TXA         copy X to A
LOOP2:  BEQ :LOOP1  if 0, next outer loop
        LSR         shift right
        BCC :LOOP2  if carry is clear, next inner loop
        INY         else increment result
        BCC :LOOP2
        INC $FC
        BNE :LOOP2  next inner loop
FINISH: LDA $FC
        RTS
```

**notes**

- With only 8 bit input possible, the maximum number of set bits is 1024; so incrementing the MSB (`INC $FC`) always has a non-zero result; hence `BNE :LOOP` always branches.
- `BEQ` following that `BNE` never branches, even not if the accumulator is zero (so I could actually add two to the BEQ parameter and save one cycle); but that doesn´t matter: `LSR` will clear the carry and set the zero flag, `BCC` will hop to `LOOP2` and the `BEQ` to `LOOP1`.
- I´m not completely sure (it´s been so long I actually coded on the C64), but it may fail if the range is larger than 127: `CPX $02` is actually a substraction; if the result is >127, the negative flag may be set, so `BMI` would end the routine.
- I hope I got the branching parameters correct - I assembled the machine code manually.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 39 bytes

```perl
map$\+=(sprintf'%b',$_)=~y/1//,$_..<>}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlRttWo7igKDOvJE1dNUldRyVe07auUt9QXx/I1NOzsaut/v/f0MDAgMsISPzLLyjJzM8r/q9bkAMA)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
_.to(_)flatMap(_.toBinaryString)count(49==)
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pUPYRlXNQUSsI2Kp0bzqrw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
I2Bʂ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhZLPY2cTjUtKU5KLoaKLFhpaGBgwGUEJCACAA)

##### Explanation

```python
I2Bʂ  # Implicit input
I     # Inclusive range
 2B   # Convert each to binary
   ʂ  # Sum each inner list
      # Implicit output of sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>54</s> 50 btyes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzRCsIgGEbve4q/OyUR54paY88yxBwLTGkqDLJnN7Xb7bv4bs7hLMH5NBl4iadBGD4HyNPKg4ABUtT30HIyl49IUzrMmE5WPxAjUZI1ytNKpQ3Gj9YohzBOfS3UE86pxY/qfUQCNYwAZzjfFfdbuPIinJtu0yDQFrrDeEnvlP/p0r507S1L3/QD)

```rust
|l:u32,h:u32|(l..=h).fold(0,|c,x|c+x.count_ones())
```

`count_ones` does the heavy lifting of counting the number of ones in each number here.

Used `fold` to avoid turbofish from `sum`.

Ungolfed:

```rust
|low: u32, high: u32| (low..=high).fold(0, |total, x| total + x.count_ones())
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 26 bytes

```ruby
:!~|:sum+(~:digits&2|:sum)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWu6wU62qsiktztTXqrFIy0zNLitWMwAKaEAWrChTcog0NdIwMYiECCxZAaAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
\d+
$*
M!&`(?<=^(1+),.*)\1.*
+`(1+)\1
$1x
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkWbS0WLy1dRLUHD3sY2TsNQW1NHT0szxlBPi0s7AcSNMeRSMazgMvz/39DAQMfIwAAA)

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkWbS0WLSzshJknDUFtTx9AwxpBLxVDHUEUNKAgSAvG1DbgM//830bEAAA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 10 bytes

```
R²2Br.`0-L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z/o0CYjpyK9BANdn////5v8NwcA)

Answer (score 0):

## C (GCC), 49 bytes

This function takes lower (`a`) and upper (`b`) bounds. Output is either through global `c` or by return value (if your ABI uses the same register from accumulating and function return).

```c
c;f(a,b){for(c=b-a?f(a+1,b):0;a;a/=2)c+=a&1;a=c;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##bcpBDsIgEIXhtZxiUqOBlCo0JiaO6EXc0KEoiVKDrZumZ8cat27e4ns/VVeinAk9t7IRo@8SJ9NU9jxDqWc6KLRot6YWVBq71mgN4ZTZMkS6D66F46t3odvcToyF2MPDhsjfXXACRrZ4ptk8L1buEgsJnu8k7CUoIfDPqZWSUH/nF6S2H1IEhWzKHw) (output by return value)

### Acknowledgments

- -5 bytes thanks to [GPS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41885/gps)
- -1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Comment: 50 bytes: c;f(a,b){c=b-a?f(a+1,b):0;for(;a;a/=2)c+=a&1;a=c;}

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, 78 bytes

With currying syntax

```
x=>y=>[...Array(y-x+1)].map((e,i)=>(i+x).toString`2`).join``.split`1`.length-1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 82 bytes

```
func[a b][s: 0 until[n: a until[if n % 2 = 1[s: s + 1]1 > n: n / 2]b < a: a + 1]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtBCsIwFAX3PcVsXLkwiYIQ1EN0G/4itQ0E5CNNe/5ooFJ3M7x58zTWfhqDdMnXtOozRAYJxWNYdcmvoJ64YU4oBxx3bEsKR6xYHnwj5YSTgRuxPdpSpL7nrAuJC9fux9YYnDG7c/5jVz8)

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 80 bytes

```
let c s e=Seq.sumBy(fun x->seq{for i=0 to 31 do yield x>>>i&&&1}|>Seq.sum){s..e}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NC4IwAIbv/ooXIamDsmnQJXcIugcdo4PoFgPdcpuhqL99KXTL6/O8H8LGpTbc@5o7lLDg@Z23ie2ay7AXnUIfM8vbUWgDmRM4jYyi0hgkryv0jDEZRRGdJ/brHUabJHz2j/NVOTPctFSOPYN1vymkQmFeH@TBcnbECRPD2ywJoRDuZLhiSpCSbbGabYVsG6f/mPgv)

For each number `x` in the range, shift the number by `i` bytes, AND it with 1, and add that to the sum for that number. Finally add all the shifting results for each number and return it.

It does the shift 32 times, since the starting and ending numbers are of type `int32`.

Answer (score 0):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 59

```
:
s/\b(1+) (11\1)/\1 1\1 \2/
t
:a
s/(1+)\1/\10/
ta
s/0| //g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3c8xDoJQEATQfk8xjQIaXMaSs/xGEQ0NEPYnNJzd9YOJlbWFr5hNZqq19uZei2m45jwWyMnAQgORLsJZJUp9Sfu6BqahStVaVAtUH256Oug4dX28I9tZhj0WzA3KRltnAr4JP8AvhD8A/gnZXtnyOYyxG3rzcnoB)

Input and output as [unary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5349/11259).  Input is two space-separated unary integers.

The TIO has a footer line to convert to decimal, as a convenience.

The `1000, 2000` testcase takes too long - TIO times out after 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 80 bytes

```
proc P a\ b {while \$a<=$b {incr c [regexp -all 1 [format %b $a]]
incr a}
set c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUxLCsIwFNznFEOJO4W0CoLoHbpPs3gNUQupDWlEoeTs8bW4mC/DJOtLCXGyaEEdeiyf5@AdOknXm@Q4vGyEhY7u4b4BB/IeNfR9iiMl7HpIMkZsK8pidgk2Fz9S@N@JE86iVmgU8yqsODKaNW@FEhlLeKcZlaQ9ZH@BbvmXnaly@QE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
(a,b)->sum(count_ones.(a:b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59s@18jUSdJU9euuDRXIzm/NK8kPj8vtVhPI9EqSVPzf0FRZl5JTp5GsoaJjrmmJheCb2hgoGNkYKCpqYAqCBYFCnP9BwA)

---

If input can be sent in in the form of a range (i.e. c(4:7) instead of c(4,7)), that saves 6 bytes:

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
r->sum(count_ones.(r))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59s@79I1664NFcjOb80ryQ@Py@1WE@jSFPzf0FRZl5JTp5GsoaJlbmmJheCb2hgYGVkYKCpqYAqCBYFCnP9BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```
param($n,$m)$n..$m|%{for(;$_){$s+=$_-band1;$_=$_-shr1}};$s
```

Test script:

```
$f = {
param($n,$m)$n..$m|%{for(;$_){$s+=$_-band1;$_=$_-shr1}};$s
}

@(
,(4,7,8)
,(10,20,27)
,(100,200,419)
,(1,3,4)
,(1,2,2)
,(1000,2000,5938)
) | % {
    $n,$m,$e=$_
    $r = &$f $n $m
    $c = $r -eq $e

    "$c : $n , $m ---> $e = $r"
}
```

Output:

```
True : 4 , 7 ---> 8 = 8
True : 10 , 20 ---> 27 = 27
True : 100 , 200 ---> 419 = 419
True : 1 , 3 ---> 4 = 4
True : 1 , 2 ---> 2 = 2
True : 1000 , 2000 ---> 5938 = 5938
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Pyt](http://www.github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki), 3 bytes

Input is the larger number then the smaller number

```
ŘĦƩ
```

Explanation:

```
      Implicitly get the two numbers x and y (x<y)
Ř     Push [x,x+1,...,y]
Ħ     Get the Hamming weight of each element of the array
Ʃ     Sum the list of Hamming weights
      Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6Iwjy46t/P/fyMCAy9DAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code, 14 bytes

```
00000000: 31c0 f30f b8d9 01d8 4139 d17e f5c3       1.......A9.~..
```

Takes bottom of range in ecx, and top of range in ebx. Returns in eax.

Assembly (NASM syntax):

```
section .text
	global func
func:
					;1st arg = ecx, 2nd arg = edx
	xor eax, eax			;reset total
	loop:
		popcnt ebx, ecx		;get number of binary 1's in current number and store in ebx
		add eax, ebx		;add ebx to total (eax)
		inc ecx			;increase the current number (ecx) in range
		cmp ecx, edx
		jle loop		;repeat while current number (ecx) >= range max (edx)
	ret				;return the register eax
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZRtb5swEMdfw6c4Ra2AKqQNqTQttH0xrdPe7QOMKTL2hdCCjWzTMHX97NnZNFoeukgBfPe7@/vOByUzmx1nFu7uHn98gwe4tm13zWbMtJCDdLd0jc16kR16UjWuuBI4UwQi3yiYhDhY1BJqaWG1YtbquuwtrlZxvGbGctY0SQLrXvKYkCn9kxzCltUyTl7DTpNhHReTeH4zhewmgSVcikIWk6kPISsZk/wI9OQHqGNP4SkszsDp4gzKzqHsTHbU/UjYK3vpt8m@n8b25YznRViEFefH7aPmHkJHjU2lSrsaIW0XmY9W5ZPo2w7Sr0ccyQh8oQwCtT4GzRH4ByziIUyWSiNxjxD9vEk//3q9fYOIrLy3kJbwKb3NXJSGVEBUyOjfwmM@nRPY4DCzgyXTlgrkdGfbZ4hefdfgYn6dvTl@bCJMCnl1dfXlt0Xgqpd2SatCXppCTuAidvOYJh9U5ccsxffw7zi4Gl0sdfqQhWEQkNI2u9PNOcfDadqjw9gZ5LZWEmaWxjkMqkaVrPFTG7rLMnC/3G7Q2zzaGzSwH3GqSL6gdA4TjrBUYCzjz2DQ9h1IRIECSuSMImGLIJSMrLeDVS7dyL@Hz40Fpiu4p/dsoMGTYr8UQxgMSgMystPF0RpJhdJY1oRBo1S3pDSd6jidA5aO48TlFUGyb0vUoNZQ1pLp3zCPDL29dPhaUwV7PyNBY5VG56MUlI8J8S5aumR@WQ5u814YYnImxNWSj3pBTo8aGZXmWneiEBOTuOyayQopjtPs@mJ9icFTg@BK8eV1SPOx3dTNf9I83I9poGUDmYTbiEYbjM2xPX2h3BY0VrWh75WrY0cfv91f)

C code equivalent:

```
/*
ecx=range_start
edx=range_end
eax=total
ebx=ones_count
*/

int ones_in_range(int range_start, int range_end){
	int total = 0;
	do {
		int ones_count = __builtin_popcount(range_start);
		total += ones_count;
		range_start++;	
	} while(range_start <= range_end);
	return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 15 chars, 30 bytes

```
{+/∊(⍵⍴2)⊤⍺..⍵}
```

test

```
  f←{+/∊(⍵⍴2)⊤⍺..⍵}
  1000 f 2000
5938
```

This seems ok even in the case 0 f 0 because +/⍬ is 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform) with LINQ, 82 bytes

```cs
(a,b)=>{int c=0;for(;a<=b;a++)c+=Convert.ToString(a,2).Count(x=>x=='1');return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBRa8IwFIWf7a@4b02wq20dGxJTGMJgsL1MYQ/DhxjjCLSJS1KniL@9u@pkG4zuJXBz7v3O4Uh/Ja1TbeO1eYPpzgdVM/g5pY/avDOQlfAe7mAf@SCClnDfGDnWJiRweUpYAW@JSBaUl3v8AMkztrKOMDHmCyb6fSr7fGLNRrmQzuw0OPTBg4KmE9uYQLa83HIe5zFlToXGGZDs0LKL58bqJTwJbQjdRz0EeVup9MXpoDClIityDQncUsr@VvMM5SLr0M8LHRuoDzvVoov@hT/zo95gANiirWuFZQWLvSvY2caB/TDY6LoJUc@fSoIKGcDhwn1WYnnCUga/vNDnu@AHE4YFOZ6m03WlA4mTmL5mc5rAf0v5nB5DHg7tTYLBR6M8@wQ)

Ungolfed:

```cs
(a, b) => {                     // takes in two integer inputs, separated by a comma
    int c = 0;                  // initialize the sum variable
    for(; a <= b; a++)          // from a (inclusive) to b (exclusive)
        c +=                            // add to c:
            Convert.ToString(a, 2)          // convert a to binary
                .Count(x => x == '1');      // count the number of ones in the binary form
    return c;                   // print c after the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 12 bytes

```
per@b2\['1CN

pe             Parse eval
  r@           range
    b2         convert to base2
      \[       concat
        '1CN   count the `1`.
```

[Try it online.](http://cheap.int-e.eu/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=%2210%2020%22per%40b2%5C%5B%271CN)

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, 16 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: 33c0 8bd1 d1e2 7301 4075 f93b cbe0 f3c3  3.....s.@u.;....
```

**Listing:**

```
33 C0       XOR  AX, AX         ; clear 1's counter in AX 
        INTLOOP: 
8B D1       MOV  DX, CX         ; current number into DX 
        BITLOOP: 
D1 E2       SHL  DX, 1          ; MSb into CF, ZF = ( DX == 0 )
73 01       JNC  BITZERO        ; if a zero, check ZF
40          INC  AX             ; increment counter 
        BITZERO: 
75 F9       JNZ  BITLOOP        ; if DX > 0 keep looping 
3B CB       CMP  CX, BX         ; is CX < BX? 
E0 F3       LOOPNZ INTLOOP      ; if not, decrement CX and loop 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, low range number in `BX`, high number in `CX`.  Result in `AX`.

Note: There is another [IA machine code submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166199/count-ones-in-range/175689#175689) which uses the [`POPCNT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT) instruction introduced with SSE4 requiring an Intel Core or later architecture.  This one will run on any `8086` or later CPU.

**Test program:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
Tr@DigitCount[Range@##,2,1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6TIwSUzPbPEOb80ryQ6KDEvPdVBWVnHSMcwVu1/QFFmXomCQ3q0oYGOkUEsFxIfJIAiomOMwjNCVQ1WbhD7/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 43 bytes

```
A*B*O:-A>B,O=0;- \A*B*S,O is S+popcount(A).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/31HLScvfStfRzknH39bAWlchBiQSrOOvkFmsEKxdkF@QnF@aV6LhqKn330pXwdDAwEBBS8EIQvnrKBQUZQJl/YGyAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Aya](https://github.com/aya-lang/aya), 15 bytes

```
[2|,10 2.&].FW
```

Apparently there's no `to binary` built-in, so it needs to be done manually. Takes inputs on the stack.

### Example Session

Given that there's no try it online, I figured I'd provide an example console session, placing the program in a function for convenience. It would work outside the function and without the variable names, as taking input from the stack is an allowed default for stack languages.

```
aya> {a b, a b[2|,10 2.&].FW} :f
{a b, a b [2|, 10 2 .&] .F W} 
aya> 4 7 f
8 
aya> 10 20 f
27 
aya> 100 200 f
419 
aya> 1 3 f
4 
aya> 1 2 f
2 
aya> 1000 2000 f
5938
```

### Explained

```
[2|,10 2.&].FW­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
[2|,      ]     # ‎⁡Over each number in a range from the first input to the second
        .&      # ‎⁢  Convert the number
    10          # ‎⁣  From base 10
       2        # ‎⁤  To base 2
           .F   # ‎⁢⁡Flatten the resulting list
             W  # ‎⁢⁢And summate
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒k(≥mâΣ
```

Takes two loose inputs in reversed order.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EnZGo86l@YeXnRu8f//5gomXEYGCoYGQBJEGXAZKxhyGYGwAUTAAAA)

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately, MathGolf lacks a ranged-list builtin, so 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) are used for that..

```python
╒k(≥     # Push a list in the range [secondInput,firstInput]:
╒        #  Push a list in the range [1, (first) implicit input-integer]
 k       #  Push the second input-integer
  (      #  Decrease it by 1
   ≥     #  Remove that many leading items from the ranged-list
    m    # Map over each integer in this list:
     â   #  Convert it to a binary-list
      Σ  # Take the flattened sum of this list of lists of bits
         # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 54 bytes

```swift
let f={($0+0...$1+0).reduce(0){$0+$1.nonzeroBitCount}}
```

`f(_:_:)` takes a lower bound and an upper bound.

There aren't really any fancy tricks here, just a simple call to `reduce(_:_:)` and some hints for the type checker in the form of `+0`s.